# Cybele TN Bridge Host Integration in WPF

Tags: c#, winforms, wpf-controls, activex

Has anybody out there worked with Cybele Software TN Bridge Host Integration Pack in WPF(.Net)?

The package consists of three dlls.

- Cybele.TNBridge.dll
- Cybele.TNBridge.Vcl.dll
- Mono.Security.dll

And the display component they exported is Cybele.TNBridge.Display : System.Windows.Forms.Control, ISupportInitialize, IEditable

Whoever worked this component, please shine me some light where to start..
Any websites, tutorial sites, anything is welcome to begin with.
The product manual is not kind enough to look at and work directly in wpf environment.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your frustration.  I'm using TN Bridge for .NET in an application for my employer and finding the documentation from Cybele to be so thin that I've got to email their customer support rather frequently.  I'm sure answering my emails is not the most productive use of their time but I wouldn't be emailing if their documentation were more complete.

Perhaps more frustrating is that I've not previously written code for Tn3270 communication and didn't know that you have to explicitly put WaitFor calls in the code after connecting, issuing commands, etc.  I'm used to WebServices or WCF calls where code execution doesn't continue until the connection is established or return values arrive from the call unless you explicitly call those services asynchronously.  I'm realizing now that in the world of TN3270 everything is asynchronous.  It would have been nice to know this three weeks ago!

Perhaps the more frustrating aspect of programming for TN3270 is exemplified by your asking this question three and a half months ago and not getting a single answer.  3270 isn't that unusual a protocol but either very few people are programming it in .NET or those who are won't talk about it for some reason.

In answer to your question: yes, there are a couple of us in the .NET world using Cybele's TN Bridge for .NET.

Comment: Hi Good to hear from someone who is actually working on it.  Is your project work with UI Thread in WPF or Winform?

Comment: I should have said I was *evaluating* TN Bridge and we're now leaning toward Rocket Software's Passport HIO because of Rocket's documentation, support, and willingness to allow access to the engineers who write the product to help us resolve any issues we have.  My project does not have a UI: it's a multi-threaded (up to 1000 threads), no-GUI, server process.